# importing org.apache.commons.math.stat.StatUtils eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse

I am wanting to use the StatUtils in a project i am working on. How do i get the ability to import that package in my eclipse project?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on your project, then a menu will be showed, choose "Properties", click "Java Build Path" and choose "Libraries" tag, you can click "Add JARs..." or "Add External JARs..." to add the package you want.

You can refer to the website : http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java)

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is the 2 option ^^
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-114.htm -- good eclipse tutorial!
GL.

Answer (score 0):

Point your browser to http://commons.apache.org/math/. Then read the instructions. Most particularly, download the jar file from the download area, and then add that jar file to your project's build classpath in the Eclipse build path options for the project.